# Setting up a script to edit a whitelist of extensions in registry

Tags: powershell, loops, registry

I am learning some script writing in powershell by writing a script I can use to help setup computers at work by blocking extensions in chrome and edge and creating a whitelist, however my script isn't behaving the way that it should and I am not sure where I have messed up the logic. I also really hope that it is decipherable, I will be putting a lot of effort into tidying it up in that respect once I have it doing what I want it to be doing.

This is the bit of the script that seems to be messing up, I have included my variables to help understand what it is that I am trying to do and I have the PoSh Registry module installed for the registry tweaks.

```
    #Registry Variables
$DefaultAppUpdateURL = "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
#Extension Data for whitelisting
$Serene = "falnmchlgbngpmiifgbpgophmdflgiff;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"
$Lastpass = "hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"
$ADBlocker = "gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"

 $computer = "MS107B44463257"

#Extensions for Whitelisting
    $WhitelistApps = $Serene,$Lastpass,$ADBlocker

Foreach ($App in $WhitelistApps)      
    {$NumWhitelistedEdgeApps = get-RegValue -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionInstallForcelist |Select-Object -Property value | Measure-Object |Select-Object -ExpandProperty count
     $NumWhitelistedChromeApps = get-RegValue -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist |Select-Object -Property value | Measure-Object |Select-Object -ExpandProperty count
     $NewChromeEntry = $NumWhitelistedChromeApps + 1
     $NewEdgeEntry = $NumWhitelistedEdgeApps + 1        
     
     #Getting whitelist registry entries to see if they exist and are correct
      $EdgeWhitelistEntry = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionInstallForcelist |Select-Object -ExpandProperty data
      $ChromeWhitelistEntry = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist |Select-Object -ExpandProperty data   
    
     $SetEdgeWhitelistValue = Set-RegString -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionInstallForcelist -value $NewEdgeEntry -data $App -force
     $SetChromeWhitelistValue = Set-RegString -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist -value $NewChromeEntry -data $App -force
     
     
      If ($EdgeWhitelistEntry -eq $App -and $ChromeWhitelistEntry -eq $app)
        {write-host "$app on $computer is whitelisted in Edge and Chrome 1" -ForegroundColor Green}
    
        Elseif ($EdgeWhitelistEntry -ne $App -and $ChromeWhitelistEntry -eq $app)
        {write-host "$app on $computer is whitelisted Chrome but not Edge" -ForegroundColor Red
        $SetEdgeWhitelistValue
        Write-Host "$app is whitelisted for chrome and edge 2" -ForegroundColor Green}
    
        Elseif ($EdgeWhitelistEntry -eq $App -and $ChromeWhitelistEntry -ne $app)
        {write-host "$app on $computer is whitelisted Edge but not Chrome" -ForegroundColor Red
        $SetChromeWhitelistValue
        Write-Host "$app is whitelisted for chrome and edge 3" -ForegroundColor Green}
        
        
        Elseif ($EdgeWhitelistEntry -ne $App -and $ChromeWhitelistEntry -ne $app)
        {write-host "$app is not whitelisted for Chrome or Edge " -ForegroundColor Red
        $SetEdgeWhitelistValue
        $SetChromeWhitelistValue
        Write-Host "$app on $computer is whitelisted for chrome and edge 4" -ForegroundColor Green}
        
        else 
        {Write-Host "adding $app on $computer failed" -ForegroundColor red}}
```

I have put the numbers in the write-host outputs so I know what bit of the code it is executing to make it easier during troubleshooting. These will be removed for my final code.

The first time I run it, everything seems to do what I want it to do, it places entries into the registry for the 3 extensions I am testing with currently, which is Serene Lastpass and ADBlocker and gives me the following output.

```
falnmchlgbngpmiifgbpgophmdflgiff;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx is not whitelisted for Chrome or Edge 
falnmchlgbngpmiifgbpgophmdflgiff;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx on MS107B44463257 is whitelisted for chrome and edge 4
hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx is not whitelisted for Chrome or Edge 
hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx on MS107B44463257 is whitelisted for chrome and edge 4
gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx is not whitelisted for Chrome or Edge 
gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx on MS107B44463257 is whitelisted for chrome and edge 4
```

However when running it for a second time, instead of just saying that all 3 extensions exist on both the chrome and edge whitelists it writes them again to the registry and gives me the following output

```
falnmchlgbngpmiifgbpgophmdflgiff;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx on MS107B44463257 is whitelisted in Edge and Chrome 1
hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx on MS107B44463257 is whitelisted in Edge and Chrome 1
gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx on MS107B44463257 is whitelisted in Edge and Chrome 1
```

Each subsequent run of the loop gives the same results as the above output but it keeps writing new entries into the registry, it looks like it checks the registry, sees that the extensions are already there, hits the first part of my If statement and then writes another set into the registry anyway. So if I run the loop 4 times I will end up with 12 entries into the whitelist in the registry.

I have also tried changing the order of my If statements and I switched the top If statement for the bottom ElseIf statement and it was still just hitting the top statement, executing it and writing in the extra entries.

I don't understand where the writing is coming from because I haven't asked it to make any registry changes in the part of the statement that I am getting the write host output for.

############################################################################
EDIT:
OK, So I have been through and simplified the code and I have come up with the following and it is still doing the multiple entries. I have tried adding a one liner that I have used in another script that should grab a list of the current registry entries and their data, and then compare that to the list extensions that I wish to add and remove the ones that are doubled up.

```
    #Registry Variables
    $DefaultAppUpdateURL = "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"

    #Extension Data for whitelisting
    $Serene = "falnmchlgbngpmiifgbpgophmdflgiff;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"
    $Lastpass = "hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"
    $ADBlocker = "gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"


    #Extensions for Whitelisting
    $NewChromeWhiteListedApps = $Serene,$Lastpass,$ADBlocker
#Getting whitelist registry entries to see if they exist in the list
              $ChromeWhitelistRegistryList = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist |Select-Object -ExpandProperty data  
    
        <#This Gets a list of Extensions that are currently installed in the browsers and removes them from the list of Extensions to be whitelisted so we can only add single entries into the registry
        rather than new entries for each time the script is run #>
        $WhitelistedChromeAppsToBeAllowed = $NewChromeWhiteListedApps.Where{$_.Name -notin $ChromeWhitelistRegistryList}
            
        
        Foreach ($App in $WhitelistedChromeAppsToBeAllowed)      
            {<#This is for setting the name of the Extension in the registry, it will count the number of entries in the ForceInstall registry key for both chrome and edge, add 1 and use that as the name 
            of the next entry to add the app data into #>
             
             $NumWhitelistedChromeApps = get-RegValue -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key $ChromeWhiteList |Select-Object -Property value | Measure-Object |Select-Object -ExpandProperty count
             $NewChromeEntry = $NumWhitelistedChromeApps + 1
                   
             
             
            #This is to set the extension in the registry
             Set-RegString -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key $ChromeWhiteList -value $NewChromeEntry -data $App -force}
```

###########################################################################
EDIT number 2
I managed to work my way around it with an IF statement

```
#Extension Registry Variables
$DefaultAppUpdateURL = "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"

#Extension Data for whitelisting
$Serene = "falnmchlgbngpmiifgbpgophmdflgiff;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"
$Lastpass = "hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"
$ADBlocker = "gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom;$DefaultAppUpdateURL"


#Extensions for Whitelisting
$NewChromeWhiteListedApps = $Serene,$Lastpass,$ADBlocker
    
#Getting whitelist registry entries to see if they exist and are correct
$ChromeWhitelistRegistryList = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key $ChromeWhiteList |Select-Object -ExpandProperty data  
 
      
    Foreach ($App in $NewChromeWhiteListedApps)      
        {<#This is for setting the name of the Extension in the registry, it will count the number of entries in the ForceInstall registry key for both chrome and edge, add 1 and use that as the name 
        of the next entry to add the app data into #>
         
         $NumWhitelistedChromeApps = get-RegValue -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key $ChromeWhiteList |Select-Object -Property value | Measure-Object |Select-Object -ExpandProperty count
         $NewChromeEntry = $NumWhitelistedChromeApps + 1
               
                If ($ChromeWhitelistRegistryList -eq $App)
                    {Write-Host "$App is in $computer Chrome Whitelist registry" -ForeGroundColor Green}
            
                Elseif ($ChromeWhitelistRegistryList -ne $App)
                    {Write-Host "$App is not in $computer Chrome Whitelist registry" -ForeGroundColor Red
                    Set-RegString -ComputerName $computer -Hive LocalMachine -key $ChromeWhiteList -value $NewChromeEntry -data $App -force
                    Write-Host "$App is now in $computer Chrome Whitelist registry" -ForeGroundColor Green}
                Else
                    {Write-Host "Adding $App to $computer Chrome Whitelist Failed" -ForeGroundColor Red}}
```

Comment: Start by simplifying the code. Get rid of either Chrome or Edge part and see if that helps you to isolate the cause.

Comment: I have just put an edit in my original post as I seem to be limited to only about 550 characters in the comments.